# How to increase the width of the gRadio window?

Tags: r, gwidgets

I want to increase the width of gradio window using `gWidgets` package in R.
I have tried the width variable - but doesn't seem to be working.

```
gradio(c("Local File", "Teradata"), container = gwindow("Select a Datasource"),width = 500)
```

I should be able to See the window sized correctly so that "Select Datasource" is visible in the container bar. Thanks Heaps!

Comment: Try using size<- to set a widget size, or add with expand=TRUE

Comment: @jverzani doesn't seem to work. Could you please post the code that's working for you? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a starting pattern:

```
w = gwindow("title")
g = ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container=w)
rb = gradio(c("Local File", "Teradata"), container =g, expand=TRUE)
```

The `rb` will expand to fill the space allocated to `g`. If you have other widgets added with `expand=TRUE` they will share the space. If they are not added with `expand=TRUE`, the `rb` widget will grab the excess.